# How to make [textview][imagebutton][checkbox] as every row in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Sorry to make people confused. I simplified the question, which is the checkbox. Basically I want a listview like this, I want the checkbox be toggled when clicked.

> [textview][checkbox]
>
> [textview][checkbox]
>
> [textview][checkbox]
>
> [textview][checkbox]

The problem is the checkbox cannot work correctly. When I clicked a checkbox, it never be toggled.

Could anyone gives any suggestion? Thank you.

This is my codes right now:

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    Map<Integer, Boolean> map;

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> mList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mList = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            map.put(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rapid_diagnosis_row, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.multiple_question);
        textView.setText((String) mList.get(position).get("value"));

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.multiple_checkbox);
        checkBox.setChecked(map.get(position));

        // save position and checking status into tag
        checkBox.setTag(new int[] { position, checkBox.isChecked() == true ? 1 : 0 });

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // get position and checking status from tag, works fine
                int[] tag = (int[]) (v.getTag());
                int p = tag[0];
                int c = tag[1];

                // try to get checking status from the clicked view, not works
                // which is always true
                boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
                // try to toggle the clicked (checkbox) view, not works
                // the checkbox pressed never be toggled
                ((CheckBox) v).toggle();

                // save status into a hashmap, works fine
                mSimpleAdapter.map.put(p, (c == 1 ? true : false));
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: "checkbox cannot work correctly.", what is actually happening ??????

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you only want to check the check boxes or just want to retrieve value of check boxes on another Activity or Intents?

Comment: Thank you guys, I want to click the checkbox and get it be checked.

Comment: I implemented OnClickListener on MyAdapter and checkBox.setOnClickListener(this).
Then I added   public void onClick(View v) {
   boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
   ((CheckBox) v).toggle();
  } and still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replace the following toggle() line:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // ((CheckBox) v).toggle();
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        if (checked) {
            ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

However I still don't understand why toggle() cannot works.

Thank you guys.